# Replacement for Coda Slider 2.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coda-slider

Does anyone have a suggestion for a replacement to [Coda Slider 2.0](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) ?

While the product is good the support community and developer have gone awol....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - Replaced this with http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but in case anyone stumbles here, I've taken over the Coda Slider from Niall, and it now lives [here](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/).

Further, I've created a responsive version, which lives [here](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/).

Take Care